# Is it possible to get live traffic layer data from android google api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the live traffic data for a point(provided lat & long), is there any Google Maps API service which can provide me the Google Maps traffic layer data for a specified point?

Answer (score 0):

Hello [@R AaHul Dutta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2202678/r-aahul-dutta),

Thanks for inquiring about this feature and for helping to keep this conversation alive. At the moment, the [`google.maps.TrafficLayer`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/#TrafficLayer) class does not support `Typical` data since the class is defaulted to `autoRefresh: true`.

You could help the community by showing support in the Google Public Issue Tracker's [existing feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829567). Feel free to show us your support for new features and don't forget to follow our [blog](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/) for feature roll-outs, and bug fixes as [new versions of the Google Maps JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#documentation-for-the-api-versions) roll-out.

Comment: Thanks brother :)